# Restrict #errors after xdmp:validate

Tags: xsd, marklogic, xsd-validation

When validating an XML document using an XSD I am interested in all errors the document has.

However, `xdmp:validate` crashes after validating a large (50MB) XML document that contain a lot of elements with errors (10.000+ attributes are missing). The process just stops and dies.

Now, when using the validate expression this doesn't happen.

```
validate strict {$doc}
```

The main difference is that `xdmp:validate` returns all errors, while the expression returns after the first error.

Question is : Can I limit the number of errors `xdmp:validate` reports back? I want to stop after 100 errors. Or can I somehow have the expression continue validating until it hits 100 errors?

Answer (score 1):

Use `validate full { $node }` This will give you all the errors.

Comment: Thank you. This is an undocumented feature, at least it is not in the MarkLogic online documentation. Unfortunately it also crashes the validation process, just like xdmp:validate.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend also reporting a defect to ML.   This should not 'crash' without at minimum some kind of diagnostic error, and at best it shouldnt crash with a document in the size range stated (memory permitting).

Comment: This is indeed unwanted behaviour and we will definitely report this to MarkLogic and ask for a workable solution.